# Calculating Divisors & Outputting a String to a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Good evening,

I am trying to finish up a simple school GUI project involving JFrame, but I am stuck on the returning the Divisors properly and then displaying them with the feedback.setText() part.The instructions are as follows:

Write a java code that creates a GUI to accept an integer from the user as the input, and creates all the divisor of the input value. Your frame should contain the following components:

JLabel: Enter an integer to find all it divisor

JTextField: to read the input from the user

JButton: to start the process

JLabel: to show the output <----Main Issue

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.lang.*;



    public class DivisorException extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//data fields
final int WIDTH = 300; 
final int HEIGHT = 200;
public String divisors;
private int num;
private JButton find = new JButton("Find"); 
private JLabel question =  new JLabel("Enter a number to find all of its divisors"); 
private JTextField answer = new JTextField(8); 
private JLabel feedback = new JLabel("");


//constructor
public DivisorException(){

    //call super class constructor  --> "Name the Window"
    super("Divisor");

    //set characteristics
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    //add components
    add(question); 
    add(answer); 
    answer.addActionListener(this);
    add(find);
    find.addActionListener(this);
    add(feedback);
    }


 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
            num = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText());
                if(e.getSource().equals(find)){
                feedback.setText("The divisors are: " + divisors);

                }


            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                feedback.setText("Invalid input. Enter an integer!");
                answer.setText("");
                }
        }


    private String divisor(int num){

        String divisors = "";
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
            if(num % i == 0){

                divisors = (i + ", ");          
            }
        }
        return divisors;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, as best as I can tell, you never call `divisor` or assign the result to `divisors`, therefore `divisors` is `null`

Comment: You also need to change `divisors = (i + ", ");` to `divisors += (i + ", ");` or preferably, make use of `StringJoiner`

Comment: I tried assigning the result of num to divisor with the toString() method before ending the for loop with no avail. Also thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yes, but `divisors` is declared as a local variable in `divisor`, so it has no effect on the instance field of the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few of issues

1. You're not calling `divisor`, nor are you assigning the value to anything, so `divisors` is always `null`
2. You're shadowing the `divisors` instance field in `divisor`, so anything you assign to it won't be reflected else where
3. You're not appending the result of the loop to `divisors`, so you'll only get the last value

To start with, I'm going to change the `divisor` slightly to demonstrate what I mean...

```
private String divisor(int num) {

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            sj.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

First, I've removed the declaration of `divisors` and replaced it with a `StringJoiner`, it's simpler and gives a nicer result, but highlights the shadowing issue.

Next, I've updated the `actionPerformed` method to actually call the `divisor` method and assign the result to  `divisors`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText());
        if (e.getSource().equals(find)) {
            divisors = divisor(num);
            feedback.setText("The divisors are: " + divisors);

        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        feedback.setText("Invalid input. Enter an integer!");
        answer.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, StringJoiner has never been mentioned in any of my first few Java classes. Breaking down and explaining the issues I was having. Makes a whole lot more sense the way you formatted it.

Comment: @HurricaneIvan `StringJoiner` is new to Java 8 ... and I LOVE it! It's one of those things that got added with little fanfare but is one of the most useful things I found